# 500 error when using AWS API gateway as webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use AWS Lambda function with API gateway endpoint as weebhoks. The problem is that after a few requests I get 500 (or sometimes 503) errors. In Cloudwatch I can see that the request does not even trigger Lambda. So API gateway throws the errors. If I am waiting a short time then it everyhting is working fine again.

In Cloudwatch of API gateway I can only see the error status, no more.

Comment: How long are the requests taking to complete? API Gateway has a maximum hard limit of 30 seconds timeouts. If your service can’t respond in under 30 seconds, API Gateway will assume it’s unavailable and stop waiting.

Comment: @zemaj max 10 seconds (but mainly 2-3)